# Angularjs set selected value to datasourse

Tags: angularjs, select

I need to put a mark selected=true in the element collection that is now selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sourseSelector">Sourses</label>
   <select id="sourseSelector" class="form-control" ng-options="true as sourse.text for sourse in sourses" ng-model="sourse.selected"></select>
</div>
```

And code in controller

```
$scope.sourses = [
   {name: "peoples", text: "", selected:false},
   {name: "firms", text: "", selected:false},
   {name: "clients", text: "", selected:false},
   {name: "contracts", text: "", selected:false}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial code you're trying to select the field's value with a predicate (`sourse.selected`) and not a controller property. `ng-model` doesn't allow for that, which is why it fails to work as you'd hope.

To set a default value in the select box based on a property (like 'selected'), try assigning the select's `ng-model` directive to an entirely new property, then using `ng-init` to set it on startup. To update an object's `selected` flag each time you change the value in the select box, take advantage of the [ngChange directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

HTML:

```
<label for="sourseSelector">Sourses</label>
<select id="sourseSelector" class="form-control" ng-init="setDefault()" ng-options="sourse.name for sourse in sourses" ng-model="selectedSourse" ng-change="updateSelectedSourse()" >
```

JS:

```
$scope.sourses = [
   {name: "peoples", text: "Ppl", selected:false},
   {name: "firms", text: "Frm", selected:false},
   {name: "clients", text: "Cli", selected:true},
   {name: "contracts", text: "Con", selected:false}
];

$scope.setDefault = function() {
    $scope.selectedSourse = $scope.sourses.filter(function(obj) { return !!obj.selected; })[0];  
};

$scope.deselectAll = function(sources) {
    sources.forEach(function(source) { source.selected = false; });
};

$scope.updateSelectedSourse() {
    $scope.deselectAll($scope.sourses);
    $scope.selectedSourse.selected = true;
};
```

This grabs the first object in the array for which selected is true and sets it to the `$scope` property linked to your select field's `ng-model` on startup. If none of the values have a selected value of "true", the field will remain blank. As you change the selected value, `updateSelectedSourse()` will iterate over all your sourses, ensure they're not selected, and then flag the newly chosen item as the selected one. This all revolves around that `selectedSourse`property you created for your `ng-model`: it's already updating itself each time you select a new option, you're just having to manually update the object's data as well.

Here's a live demo @ jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15573/ (updated to include the `selected` flagging on change)

Some more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: You did not understand. I need to do just as I have. Change the selected element property "selected". I will have more elements <select/> and each subsequent should filter collection for this property.

Comment: I see - I think I understand better now. You want to update the `sourses` object that has been selected each time the selected option is changed on the page, correct? I'll rejigger my answer to match this.

Comment: The updated answer will allow for any number of <select> options and will properly mark the one that has been selected. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Now everything is working properly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a separate model property and assign it to the selected item and bind it using `ng-model`:

```
$scope.sourses = [
   {name: "peoples", text: "peoples"},
   {name: "firms", text: "firms"},
   {name: "clients", text: "clients"},
   {name: "contracts", text: "contracts"}
];
```

This will select the second option:

```
$scope.selectedSource = $scope.sourses[1];
```

View:

```
<select id="sourseSelector" class="form-control" ng-options="sourse.text for sourse in sourses" ng-model="selectedSource"></select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C758IKqC19fjFxS15a14?p=preview)